# How do I draw condensed text in a canvas using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am new to javascript and need to condense text drawn into a canvas using java script. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-stretch.asp) suggests this can be done.

```
JavaScript syntax: object.style.fontStretch="expanded"
```

I noticed in css syntax however that neither `font-stretch: condensed` nor `font-stretch: expanded` appear to work and a [comment in the example in w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_font-stretch) also states *no browsers support the font-stretch property*. I am also aware this property [*will not work on just any font*](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-stretch.asp).

```js
var can = document.getElementById("textCanvas");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
        
ctx.font = "120px Arial Bold Italic";
ctx.font.fontStretch="ultra-condensed"; //condensed”; // expanded”;
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("NAME", 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="textCanvas"  width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Using `font-stretch` made no difference. I also tried `font-kerning` and `font-size-adjust`. How do I condense the font ?

Comment: Just search up "condense font canvas js" and you might find some downloadable scripts that can help.

Comment: You could also consider drawing the text to a canvas and then stretching the canvas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctx.font` is a *string*. Setting `fontStretch` or anything else on it won't change it.

Now, the correct syntax is the same as [CSS `font`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-4/#font-prop) property:

```
ctx.font = "[ [ <'font-style'> || <font-variant-css2> || <'font-weight'> || <font-stretch-css3> ]? <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]? <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar"`
```

So for setting only the font-stretch, the minimal is

```
ctx.font = "<font-stretch-css3> <'font-size'> <'font-family'>"
```

For example `ctx.font = "ultra-condensed 18px LeagueMonoVariable";` would do.

However you'll face the same limitations as with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch): browser support is limited, only a few fonts can be used, and in Chrome you need to define the font-stretch in the font-face declaration.

```js
// This example seems to work only on Chrome, as does the MDN's example
const font = '18px "LeagueMonoVariable"';
document.fonts.load(font)
  .then(() => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ['ultra-condensed', 'condensed', 'expanded', 'ultra-expanded'].forEach((stretch, i) => {
      ctx.font = stretch + ' ' + font;
      ctx.fillText('Hello ' + stretch + ' World', 10, i * 30 + 30);
    });
  });
```

```css
/* borrowed from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch */
/*
  This example uses the League Mono Variable font, developed by
  Tyler Finck (https://www.tylerfinck.com/) and used here under
  the terms of the SIL Open Font License, Version 1.1:
  http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web
*/

@font-face {
  src: url('https://tylerfinck.com/leaguemonovariable/LeagueMonoVariable.ttf');
  font-family: 'LeagueMonoVariable';
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: 1% 500%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500"></canvas>
```

[Chrome output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDnYY.png) for the ones using an other browser.

Also note that apparently the percentage notation (`n% font-size font-family`) is not supported in Chrome from context's `font`.

---

Given all these limitations, it might be worth considering an alternative solution, and the best alternative is probably to have the variant font as a separate font-face and use it as simply as possible.

```js
Promise.all([
  document.fonts.load("18px Roboto"),
  document.fonts.load("18px 'Roboto Condensed'")
])
  .then(() => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = "18px Roboto";
    ctx.fillText('Hello World', 10, 30);
    ctx.font = "18px 'Roboto Condensed'";
    ctx.fillText('Hello condensed World', 10, 60);
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<canvas id="canvas" width="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both your examples and both fonts successfully condense and expand. The second example works for both Google Chrome and Safari. The first one works only for Google Chrome. Unfortunately I can’t get either font to italicise which is one of my priorities. I need to consider Erty Seidohl’s suggestion to draw the text to a canvas and then stretch the canvas

Comment: @Greg, but the current question asks... "*How do I draw **condensed** text in a canvas using javascript?*". We can only answer the questions that are being asked. But if you read carefully my answer you'll see that it's not hard to make it italic: <font-style> is responsible for this, so just prepend `italic ` to the string you use as `font`. https://jsfiddle.net/jzogpr30/

Comment: Kaiido, yes, my question didn’t include italic. And by prepending _italic_ your second example works using both Safari and Google Chrome. You are a gem!         This answer taught me so much and saved me lots of time. Thanks.

Comment: Now it's 2022, but font-stretch percentage notation is still not supported in Chrome from context's font. Why isn't Google fixed that?